# SQL Server on Linux: Allocation unit on ext4

Tags: sql-server, linux, datafile

I'm testing SQL Server on Linux and now on the following point: 
Allocation Unit Size of the partition: I learned at SQL Server on Windows the Allocation Unit Size (sector size) must be 64K because of the pages.

Is this also required for the SQL Server on Linux and if yes is this supported on ext4? At the system requirements on the docs of Microsoft is only the information of which file system but not more details.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I learned at SQL Server on Windows the Allocation Unit Size (sector size) must be 64K because of the pages.

It doesn't *have* to be 64k, in fact you'll generally get the best performance based on your workload and the storage vendor's preferred size. If you don't know either, generally 64k will be used.

> Is this also required for the SQL Server on Linux and if yes is this supported on ext4?

It's not a requirement. If you can do testing ahead of time and figure out the sweet spot for your hardware and workload, then that would be the best. Most of the time, the performance difference is negligible unless there truly is a *bad* configuration for the hardware or workload.

> At the system requirements on the docs of Microsoft is only the information of which file system but not more details.

That's because it isn't required. You can use whatever you'd like, but if you truly wanted to find the proper value - testing is required.